# Arrow keys, home, and end not functioning in django terminal

Tags: python, django, shell

I'm using django 1.2.5 and python 2.7. For some reason the terminal type is wrong in the django shell and it is annoying the crap out of me. If I press up, down, right, left I get this:

```
>>> ^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D
```

This only happens in `./manage.py shell`. It's not a problem in the normal python interpreter and it happens independent of screen being on. Any thoughts?

EDIT: This is the result of `import code; code.interact()`

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

Comment: To make the above comment a bit more useful: What happens if you enter `import readline` in the management shell?

Comment: @Sven absolutely nothing. I enter the shell, type `import readline`, hit enter, press up, and it says `^[[A`. Curiouser and curioser...

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.  It's clear that importing `readline` does not affect the session that is already running, but I would have expected some error message.  What happens if you enter `import code; code.interact()` after importing `readline`?

Comment: I meant: do you have readline support in the nested console?

Comment: It prints the info that it prints when you enter python or the django shell (see latest question edit). I've found that I can manually let myself into bpython after entering the `manage.py shell`, and bpython functions nominally. It's tedious to have to do every time but oh well.

Comment: No, the new console behaves the same way.

Comment: @dustynachos: Django also [imports `readlone` before starting the shell](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/core/management/commands/shell.py#L62).  Usually, importing `readline` either fails, or enables readline support.  On your system, the import succeeds but the support isn't enabled anyway.  Sorry, no further ideas :)

Comment: Maybe it's not loading the key completions file? Strange, in any case, it should do the equivalent of `tput smkx`, and you should see ^[0A...

Comment: @sven Thanks any how. You're a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you might just need to restart the terminal. I've had the Terminal start to act funny for no apparent reason. Though in my case the mouse clicks and movements would be printed as odd character strings.